# typescript using keyof enum with generics

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

i want to create an error code counter, but having issues with typescript using enums and generics.

this is the working version (without generics)

```
enum ErrorCode  {
    MX1 = 'MX1',
    MX2 = 'MX2'
}

type Codes = keyof typeof ErrorCode;
type ErrorCodeCounter = {
    [code in Codes]: number
}

const counter = <ErrorCodeCounter>{}
counter[ErrorCode.MX1] = 3
counter['randomCode'] = 3 // Valid TS error: 'randomCode' does not exist on type 'ErrorCodeCounter
```

How can we make we make a generic **Counter** interface, to be used as:

```
const counter = <Counter<ErrorCode>>{}
counter[ErrorCode.MX1] = 3
```

one way that comes to mind is

```
type Counter<T> = {
    [code in keyof T] : number
}
```

but that does not work. 
Any ideas how to make a generic version?

**Note** that replacing enum by interface works but i would prefer Enums over interface

```
interface ErrorCodeI {
    MS1: string;
    MS2: string;
}

type Counter<T> = {
    [code in keyof T] : number
}
const counter = <Counter<ErrorCodeI>>{}
counter['MS1'] = 3
counter['random'] = 3 // Valid TS error.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `keyof`, the enum type itself is already the union of the enum elements you want to map over:

```
type Counter<T extends PropertyKey> = {
    [code in T] : number
}


enum ErrorCode  {
    MX1 = 'MX1',
    MX2 = 'MX2'
}

const counter = <Counter<ErrorCode>>{}
counter[ErrorCode.MX1] = 3
counter['randomCode'] = 3 //ERR
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gVwHbAgJwDwBUoQB6pIAmAzlAAppyRqgDSEIAfFALxQDeAsAFBT9QA2gGM4RaAEskULAF0oALihIEAWwBG6XgF9eenhBWqoAUTRU08cf258BAWQAaARjZQA5E+fuANLwFQTgBMbp6OQe46+qJIJMBQosioaG4Y8EnoGGYWVhBMTBy6PIko6ILZcJZiEAB0XvLsAMy8JcmC7mgAhsRwqrnuDVCNQA)

Comment: this is great. didn't know about PropertyKey and couldnt' find it in docs. please share any resource with more context around this if you are aware. thanks.